# Can we directly deploy windows phone application to nokia lumia 710 using Application Deployment tool with developer paid account?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, nokia

I am developinga phonegap application, and i doubted whether Nokia lumia 710 is suitable for application checking and can we diredtly deploy application on it using Application Deployment tool with developer account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES use application deployment tool. Alternative use Windows Phone power tools http://wptools.codeplex.com/

you will need to dev unlock the phone using Windows Phone Developer Registration app supplied with WP Dev SDK